# Knife will no longer download recipes from opscode

Tags: mac-osx, chef, knife

My setup is on Mac OS X and using Chef solo

Somehow after running: knife configure -i

I can no longer download anything when I run: knife cookbook download site apache2

I get back:

ERROR: Connection refused connecting to localhost:443 for /cookbooks/site/apache2, retry 1/5

I've tried deleting the whole chef folder under /opt and reinstalling but it doesn't change anything, which configure do I need to change to fix this?

Comment: Seems like your webserver serving the cookbooks is not started (or at least is not listening on port 443).

Comment: I don't have a server I'm using chef solo?

Answer (score 0):

The knife configuration file is found in your user home path in a .chef directory (~/.chef).

When you run 'knife configure -i', this file is what is updated. Try investigating your knife.rb file in that directory and/or deleting and reconfiguring.

Comment: No it isn't in there I keep the .chef folder at the same level as my cookbooks

Comment: So it seems as though the knife.rb file in that .chef directory is overriding the community site API endpoint. Can you check to see if you have anything set to localhost there? It also might help to post a gist of your knife.rb

Comment: There's nothing in the knife.rb, I literally only set the node_name and client_key values

Comment: If you ran 'knife configure -i', it may have created a knife.rb for you in ~/.chef anyway. I would check there first to make sure all of the config lines you need for your setup are in the same file.

Comment: Oh don't worry I've checked, there's nothing there

Comment: seems you have a chef server running on localhost. check if it's started via `chef-server-ctl status`